# links to images are stored in sqllite DB, how to cache

Tags: android, caching, android-lru-cache

links to images are stored in an sqllite DB, I need to display them in a gridView. However, I was told they need to be cached to disk.

my questions is what steps do i follow ? Do I first store the links from the DB into the disk Cache object, then use the disk Cache object to populate the gridView ?

Answer (score 1):

Not only a great painter, also your friend, Picasso
http://square.github.io/picasso/